# Checking HTTP response for website using Wireshark

Tags: web-server, wireshark, packet

Is there a specific way to know if the file that we download through a web server (e.g.: Java) can be verified through Wireshark?

I want to check if the file is working perfectly from internal and external site.

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of 'verification'? You need to make sure that server sending it properly or client receiving?

Comment: i need to make sure that the file in server is working properly.

Comment: What's the reason for the Wireshark requirement?  Is it really a *requirement*?

Comment: Please explain "file is working properly". Files do not work. Servers work by sending *content*, often based on server *scripts*. Either of these are saved on a file system in form of a file.

Comment: Java is not a file, it's a language.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that file is the same on the server and on the client, you'd better use some hashing function and compare hashes. You may use `md5sum` or `sha1sum` from `coreutils` package on linux to get MD5 or SHA-1 hashes respectively or use [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/57529/how-do-i-get-the-md5-of-a-file-on-windows) to get them on Windows.